# how to find the Min value and index in an R data frame and restructure it into a Tidy data frame

Tags: r

I am using R, and have built a matrix to calculate the distance between n locations. I need to calculate the nearest neighbor for each location and populate a resultant matrix of Location ID, Nearest Neighbor ID, and the distance.

Here is the data.frame (note application code uses a function to calculate the distance from Long/Lat, below is the resultant data frame.)
I also assign the distance to itself as 999 so it won't get chosen as the nearest neighbor.

```
distdf <- data.frame("New York" = c(0, 713, 2451, 748), "Chicago" = c(713, 0, 1745, 587), "Los Angeles" = c(2451,1745, 0, 1936), "Atlanta" = c(748, 587, 1936, 0), row.names = c("New York", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Atlanta"))
 
distdf[distdf ==0]<- 9999
```

From  here, I want to find the minimum distance and the row which has that value. So the result would look like this:

```
result<- data.frame("NearNeigh" = c("Chicago", "Atl", "Atl", "Chic"), "Dist" =c(713, 587, 1936, 587), row.names = c("New York","Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Atlanta"))
```

I have been able to find the nearest neighbor through something like this, but I fear I am heading down the wrong road:

```
l1<- apply(distdf, 2, which.min)

l1df<- as.data.frame(l1)
```

Comment: Can you please check the third row value in `result`.  Shouldn't that be 'Chicago' i.e. 1745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l1` gives the index of minimum value in each column. To get the minimum value use `min`.

You can create the final dataframe as. :

```
l1 <- apply(distdf, 2, which.min)
l2 <- apply(distdf, 2, min)

result <- data.frame(City = names(distdf), 
                     NearNeigh = rownames(distdf)[l1], 
                     Dist = l2, row.names = NULL)

result
#         City NearNeigh Dist
#1    New.York   Chicago  713
#2     Chicago   Atlanta  587
#3 Los.Angeles   Chicago 1745
#4     Atlanta   Chicago  587
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  Problems solved, on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `max.col` and `pmin`

```
data.frame(NearNeigh =  names(distdf)[max.col(-distdf, 'first')],
    Dist = do.call(pmin, distdf))
```